# asp.net eval issue

Tags: asp.net, webforms

So I have a asp.net page with a repeater bound to a viewmodel

I want to show/hide a block of HTML based on if the current row property CapAssignedToUserCode is the same as the variable currentUserCode (see if statement)

there is a value in the current row for the property CapAssignedToUserCode and if I hardcode the Eval("CapAssignedToUserCode") to a string it all works

I basically want to get the current row of the repeater and pass the property CapAssignedToUserCode to the function commonCap.SameUserCode

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAnnualActionsAssigned" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="item">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCapItemId" runat="server" />
            <h4>
                <%#Eval("CategoryTitle")%>:
                <%#Eval("CategoryIndex")%></h4>
            <span class="status"><strong>Status: </strong>
                <%#Eval("CapAssignedStatus")%></span>
                <span class="status"><strong>Assigned To: </strong>
                <%#Eval("CapAssignedToFullname")%></span>
            <div class="noHighlightTable">
            usercode:<%#Eval("CapAssignedToUserCode")%>
                <%
                    if (showCompleteBtn || commonCap.SameUserCode(Eval("CapAssignedToUserCode").ToString(), currentUserCode))
                  {%>
                <a class="noHighlightBtn" onclick="OpenSPDialog('/_layouts/beim/CAPAction.aspx?capDataId=' + <%#Eval("CapDataId")%>, 'Complete Action')"
                    href="javascript:void(0);">Complete action</a>
                   <%
                  }%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call a method inline. The method has your logic/output.

```
<%# WhateverYourLogicIs( (bool) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CapAssignedToUserCode") ) %>
```

There are several other ways including checking the eval directly.
Check out:

[Conditional Logic in ASP.net page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368169/conditional-logic-in-asp-net-page)

Comment: I cant access the Container object? any ideas

Answer (score 2):

Use Eval only to render field, if you want to pass field data to method use Container.DataItem.

So your code should looks like that:

```
<%#
   if (showCompleteBtn || commonCap.SameUserCode((Container.DataItem as YourBindedType).CapAssignedToUserCode), currentUserCode))
{%>
```

Comment: I cant access the Container object? any ideas

Comment: don't you forget # after '<%' simbols ?