# If with eval in aspx

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, eval

How to set correctly if condition in .aspx file in repeater?

I'm trying to set text color if value from db is true. I want to write sth like that:

```
<%# if(Eval("correct")==true) ? <li Style="color: green"><%#Eval("answer")%></li> : <li><%#Eval("answer")%></li>
```

Comment: Have a look at this question about [Conditional Logic in ASP.net page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368169/conditional-logic-in-asp-net-page)

Comment: Thank you, but there is no "then" statement

Comment: See the accepted answer!!! it contains `then`

Comment: But I can't use THEN - it causes error!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've solved it!

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repOdpowiedzi">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <ul>

                    <li style="color: <%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("correct")) ? "green" : "black"  %>"><%# Eval("answer") %></li>
                        </ul>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Repeater ItemDataBound Event**

**Sample Code:**

```
 void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
          // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
          if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {

         DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;

             if ((bool)drv["correct"] == true) {
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1")).Text= "<li Style='color: green'>" + drv["correct"].ToString() +"</li>";
             }
             else
            {
              ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1")).Text= "<li>" + drv["correct"].ToString() +"</li>";
            }
          }
       }
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to do it in aspx page?

Comment: What about something like:

<li style="color: <% Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("correct")) ? green : black  %>"><%# Eval("answer") %></li>

What would be the correct syntax for that case?