# Check Positive Negative in Eval & Change color

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, eval

I want to change the forecolor of a label in .aspx
I tried to compare if value is > 0 then it should be Green if not then Red

the problem is in condition part
I tried to use int, double, float.. but non is working
I always get Specified cast is not valid.

This is my line

```
<asp:Label ID="TAmtLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TAmt", "{0:c}") %>' Font-Size="13pt" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor='<%# (int)Eval("TAmt") > 0 ? "#00C000" : "#C00000" %>' />
```

Comment: may we know what code is in your ConvertFromHexToColorEval?

Comment: that should not be there it is from copy paste. i removed it

Comment: Did you look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368169/conditional-logic-in-asp-net-page ?

Comment: this is different case that does not help in my case.. i know how to do the if statement in eval but the problem is that datatype

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach, and hope helps :)

Instead of the ForeColor, I used the CssClass..

```
<asp:Label ID="TAmtLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TAmt", "{0:c}") %>' Font-Size="13pt" Font-Bold="true" CssClass='<%# Convert.ToDouble(Eval("TAmt")) > 0 ? "less" : "more" %>' />
```

and implement something like this in your css

```
<style type="text/css">
    .less
    {
        color : #00C000;
    }
    .more
    {
        color : #C00000;
    }
</style>
```

converting the html colors are as complicated as this topic as it is..[convert hex code to color name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791710/convert-hex-code-to-color-name)